# Primefaces command button click avoid to call window.beforeUnload function

Tags: javascript, primefaces

In my application I am using JSF with primefaces.I need current tab close to call beforeunload function.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function()
    {
     console.info('Enter into before unload event');
    }
  </script>
```

Primefaces command button I set ajax=false attribute.When press command button it will call beforeunload function.I need avoid to call window.beforeUnload function when I press the commandButton.

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="click me"/>
```

Comment: Why do you need to avoid `window.beforeUnload`?

Comment: For example if you have a file download button. It must be ajax false. That will not unload your page, you will stay there.